# Will turning off Photo Stream make my Camera Roll not back up to iCloud?

Tags: icloud, backup, photo-stream

If I turn my Photo Stream off does my Camera Roll still get backed up in iCloud? Me and my boyfriend share iTunes accounts. His friends send pictures back and forth and they show in Photo Stream. I want to turn it off but I want to ensure my Camera Roll is still backed up to iCloud.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please don't write in all caps

Answer (score 1):

Turning off Photo Stream has no impact on iCloud Backup. The contents of your Camera Roll will remain in iCloud and will continue to be backed up providing you do not disable either Camera Roll backup or iCloud Backup.

Comment: how do I make sure camera roll is still baked up

Comment: Go to Settings → iCloud → Storage & Backup → Manage Storage → This iPhone and ensure Camera Roll is still enabled.

Comment: One thing to note is that the Photo Stream only keeps the last 1000 photos, so if you are hoping to back up all of your pictures, you are going to want to use something besides iCloud.

Comment: @dwightk This does not apply to iCloud Backup

Comment: @grgarside the Camera Roll is also somehow arbitrarily truncated (I don't know what the cutoff is). I.e. there are pictures I've taken on my phone that I never deleted and are not backed up in iCloud (photo stream or camera roll).

Comment: @dwightk Interesting — The entirety of my Camera Roll is always backed up and restored, providing there is sufficient space in my iCloud. Do you have a source?

Comment: No, just my camera roll, which doesn't have all my pictures in it.